# Proving symplectic identity

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $\Lambda$ be a skew-symmetric matrix and $Q$ a symmetric matrix. Let $\text{Id}$ be the identity matrix and $h > 0$ a real number. I am trying to prove the following identity:
$$
(\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) \Lambda (\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top = (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) \Lambda (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top
$$
Here is my attempt at this where I use the facts that $Q^\top=Q$ and $\Lambda^\top = -\Lambda$. We have,
\begin{align}
(\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) \Lambda (\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top &= (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda^\top Q) \Lambda (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda^\top Q)^\top \\
&= (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda^\top Q) \Lambda (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} Q\Lambda) \\
&= (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} Q\Lambda )^\top \Lambda (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} Q\Lambda)
\end{align}
This looks almost correct but I've got the transpose on the wrong side. Does anyone see how I can manipulate this to the correct form?

Comment: I believe you upvoted my answer as well as accepted it. I appreciate it, but I need a zero-scored accepted answer as I'm tracking for unsung-hero badge. Would you please undo your upvote? I hope you don't mind. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) \Lambda =  \Lambda(\text{Id}+\frac{h}{2} Q\Lambda)$ and $(\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top = \text{Id}-\frac{h}{2}Q\Lambda$.

Thus \begin{align} (\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) \Lambda (\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top &=  \Lambda(\text{Id}+\frac{h}{2} Q\Lambda)(\text{Id}-\frac{h}{2}Q\Lambda) \\ &= \Lambda(\text{Id} - \frac{h^2}{4}Q\Lambda Q\Lambda) \end{align}

The same argument for $-\Lambda$ (which is also skew-symmetric) yields \begin{align} (\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) \Lambda(\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top  &= -(\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) (-\Lambda)(\text{Id} - \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top \\ &= -(-\Lambda)\left(\text{Id} - \frac{h^2}{4}Q(-\Lambda) Q(-\Lambda)\right) \\ &= \Lambda(\text{Id} - \frac{h^2}{4}Q\Lambda Q\Lambda) \\ &= (\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q) \Lambda (\text{Id} + \frac{h}{2} \Lambda Q)^\top \end{align}

as desired.